# Регулярное выражение для определения гласной или согласной буквы в начале строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как составить такое регулярное выражение которое проверяет только первую букву в строке на то является она согласной или гласной?

Тут нужно как-то регулярное выражение написать

```
if (string.matches("[рег-ое выражение]")) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Кстати, вам может быть интересно: [Откуда известно соответствие между заглавными и строчными (uppercase и lowercase) символами?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546671/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-uppercase-%d0%b8-lowercase?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Должно быть достаточно такого: `str.matches("^(?i:[aeiouy]).*")`. Для кириллицы - `str.matches("^(?ui:[аеёиоуыэюя]).*")`.

- `^` обозначает начало строки
- `(?i:...)` - включает [CASE_INSENSITIVE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) для этой группы, чтобы не перечислять повторно заглавные буквы.
- `(?ui:...)` Важно! Если вы работаете с юникодом, то вышеуказанный ключ не сработает. Нужно добавить [UNICODE_CASE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE), т.е. `?ui`.
- `[aeiouy]` - все гласные. Если нужно найти все согласные, то нельзя использовать `[^aeiouy]`, т.к. в эту группу попадают вообще все символы юникода, кроме этих шести. Нужно точно так же перечислить согласные.
- `.*` - дальше сколько угодно (хоть ноль) любых символов, кроме конца строки.

Демонстрация работы с разными строками:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strs = {"abcd efjk", "hello world", "a", "E", "d", "", "\n", "юникод"};
        for (String str: strs) {
            boolean test = str.matches("^(?i:[aeiouy]).*");
            System.out.println(str + ": " + test);
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
abcd efjk: true
hello world: false
a: true
E: true
d: false
: false

: false
юникод: false
```

Comment: `.*` лишнее и не несет нагрузки кроме как на процессор ;-)

Comment: @ReinRaus однако без него в выводе функции везде `false`. ЧЯДНТ? Здесь сработало бы `find()`, но его нет у джавовых строк.

Comment: Ну да. Извините. Неочевидное  поведение :(

Comment: @ReinRaus да не за что извиняться. Надо просто через компилируемый объект регулярки это делать, тогда можно будет find.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы определить, является ли первая буква в строке гласной или согласной, можно обойтись без регулярного выражения. Достаточно определить строку со всеми гласными или согласными, а потом проверить наличие в этой строке первого символа тестируемой строки:

```
// Начинается ли строка с гласной?
String vowelsRussian = "аоуэиыеёяю"; // "aeiouy" (англ.)
String testRussian = "Ёрш сегодня не клюёт";
if (vowelsRussian.indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(testRussian.charAt(0))) != -1) {
    System.out.println(testRussian + " начинается с гласной");
}
// Для проверки на согласную букву в начале используйте 
// String consonantsRussian = "йцкнгшщзхфвпрлджбтмсч";
// String consonantsEnglish = "qwrtplkjhgfdszxcvbnm"; // "y" можно рассматривать и как гласную, и как согласную букву
```

Регулярное выражение имеет смысл использовать в более сложных сценариях. Тогда можно использовать следующее решение:

```
// Тоже самое с использованием регулярного выражения
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^[АОУЭИЫЕЁЯЮаоуэиыеёяю]").matcher(testRussian);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(testRussian + " начинается с гласной");
}
// С согласными можно так же, как и с гласными, или можно воспользоваться
// вычитанием символьных классов:
String testRussian2 = "Сегодня ёрш клюёт";
Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("^[б-щБ-Щ&&[^ОУИЕоуие]]").matcher(testRussian2);
if (m2.find()) {
    System.out.println(testRussian2 + " начинается с согласной");
}
```

См. [Java-демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/N1aVZG).

Внимание: `find()` работает оптимальнее `matches()`, так как не требует полного совпадения (не возникнет проблем со строками, содержащими символы переноса строки при меньшей нагрузке на процессор).

Подробнее о вычитании символьных классов в Java смотрите [*Регулярные выражения в Java. Часть 2*](http://easy-code.ru/lesson/java-regular-expressions-part2). В регулярке `[б-щБ-Щ&&[^ОУИЕоуие]]` нет `а`, `э`, `ю`, `я`, `ё`, так как эти гласные просто не входят в диапазон `б-щБ-Щ`.

Не стоит использовать флаг [UNICODE_CASE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE) без необходимости (так как "*Specifying this flag may impose a performance penalty*" (= "При использовании данного флага могут возникнуть проблемы с производительностью"), лучше просто перечислить необходимые нам в данном случае диапазоны символов.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ответ, вроде бы.

```
String string = "touch";
if (string.matches("^[^aeiouyAEIOUY]\\w++")) {
    System.out.println("гуд");
} else if (string.matches("^[aeiouyAEIOUY]\\w++")) {
    System.out.println("бэд");
}
```

Comment: `\\w++` лишнее, особенно два плюса. И это не сработает, когда у вас в строке только одна буква.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну так работает, а как тогда лучше сделать ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin `^[^aeiouyAEIOUY](\w+)?`

Comment: Я предложил в ответе вариант, который сработает с одной буквой.

Comment: С плюсом проблема в том, что он требует хотя бы одно вхождение. А `(\w+)?` это практически то же самое, что и `\\w*`

Answer (score 0):

Выше было отвечено как определить гласную букву (через перечисление `[aeiouy]`), как все остальные символы (`[^aeiouy]`). Согласную же букву можно определить не через полное их (согласных) перечисление, а через гласные с использованием [позитивного просмотра вперед](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4):

```
(?i)^(?=[^aeiouy])[a-z].*
```

`(?i)` - игнорируем регистр;

`^` - начало строки;

`(?=[^aeiouy])` - позитивный просмотри вперед, проверяем первый символ на несовпадение с гласными буквами без смещения указателя;

`[a-z]` - первый символ должен быть латинской буквой;

`.*` - все остальные символы в строке, если они есть.

Думаю так короче будет, чем перечислять все гласные буквы.