# Откуда известно соответствие между заглавными и строчными (uppercase и lowercase) символами?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки, любой-язык, unicode

В языках программирования бывают строковые методы, работающие с регистром (case) символов. Как правило, можно:

- Проверить, является ли символ заглавным или строчным
- Преобразовать строку в только заглавные или строчные

А ещё есть регулярные выражения с ключом case-insensitive:

```python
# например так
'/[aeiouy]/i'
# или так:
'(?i:[aeiouy])'
```

Как это вообще работает? Откуда известно соответствие между символами?

---

Вопрос возник в процессе написания ответа на другой вопрос: [Регулярное выражение для определения гласной или согласной буквы в начале строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546452/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: а для не юникод? :-)

Comment: @Grundy наверное, есть и в других кодировках что-то подобное.

Comment: @Grundy, а для не-юникод есть, например, битовая таблица признаков (`man isupper` etc), и куча других внешних источнков, которые могут даже динамически изменяться в зависимости от локали :)

Comment: Заглавная буква или строчная, а также прочие ее характеристики, описываются в категории LC_CTYPE текущей локали.

Comment: @avp не хотите ли написать ответ про локали?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, увы, я не настолько глубоко в этом разбираюсь, чтобы учить других. Идея, конечно, хорошая и как говорится, это *плодотворная дебютная идея*. Если будет время, разберусь и напишу (а пока запомню эту тему, отметив ее "звездочкой").

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Эта информация является неотъемлемой частью стандарта Unicode.

Основная часть информации есть в файле [UnicodeData.txt](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt). Он представляет собой таблицу значений, разделённых знаком `;` (т.е почти [csv](/questions/tagged/csv)). Из [документации по его структуре](http://www.unicode.org/Public//3.0-Update1/UnicodeData-3.0.1.html) нам интересны следующие столбцы (всего их 15, с 0 по 14):

- 0 Code value. Шестнадцатеричный номер символа
- 1 Character name. Название.
- 12    Uppercase Mapping. Соответствующий (строчному) заглавный символ.
- 13    Lowercase Mapping. Соответствующий (заглавному) строчной символ.
- 14    Titlecase Mapping. Соответствующий символ регистра titlecase. Это специальный регистр для случаев, когда есть особенное написание для *Заглавной* буквы в слове, написанном строчными. Пример: [ǲ](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=01F2) (это один символ!).

Примеры строк:

```
0410;CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;0430;
0430;CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;0410;;0410
```

Для `А` соответствующий lowercase символ - `а`. Соответственно, для `а` соответствующий uppercase и titlecase символ - `А`.

А вот вышеупомянутый `ǲ`. У него все три соответствия разные. (Строка разбита для удобства чтения)

```
01F2;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH SMALL LETTER Z;
    Lt;0;L;<compat> 0044 007A;;;;N;;;01F1;01F3;01F2
```

Все соответствия в файле UnicodeData.txt однозначны, т.е 1-1. Для исключений, когда одному символу соответствует несколько, есть [SpecialCasing.txt](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt). Дополнительная информация для преобразований регистров есть в [CaseFolding.txt](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/CaseFolding.txt).

Больше информации можно найти в [FAQ - Character Properties, Case Mappings & Names FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html)

Comment: [Как делать локали](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Locales)

Comment: @avp спасибо, интересная информация.