# Необъяснимое поведения регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

По идее регулярка проверяет чтобы в имени было только буквы русские и латинские и несколько дополнительных `ёЁҷҶқҚӯӮҳҲӣӢғҒ` и имя состоит от 3х до 25и символов.

```
elseif (!preg_match('/[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁҷҶқҚӯӮҳҲӣӢғҒ]{3,25}$/i', $name)) {
  $this->setFieldError("surname", "Неверный формат имени.<br>Имя должна состоять только из букв и должно содержать 3-25 букв");
  return;
}
```

На онлайн инструментах типо https://regex101.com все отлично работает но на сервере по другому работает. Например на сервере с значениями "Шухратҷон" не показывает ошибку(так и должно) а с значением "Шухрат" уже показывает ошибку.
Но ведь во втором случае тоже не должен показывать ошибку, что происходит?
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Проверяйте кодировку. В разных кодировках по-разному. В 1251 например в таблице ASCII есть разрыв, и правильно делить а-о п-я , т.к. в середине кодировки есть другие символы. Приведеный пример в utf-8 работает верно.

Comment: кодировка UTF-8 без BOM @nick_n_a

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁҷҶқҚӯӮҳҲӣӢғҒ]{3,25}$/u`

Comment: @Visman насколько я знаю ^ это отрицания. Но я всеравно проверил и не получилось

Comment: В моем варианте `^` не отрицание, а начало строки. Отрицание это вот так `[^a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @Visman ясно, но я попробовал не сработало

Comment: Значит у вас что-то ни то с php на сервере :)

Comment: @nick_n_a, интересно, откуда же там в кодировке 1251 разрыв взялся между о и п?

Comment: @Visman с сервером все в порядке, посмотрите в ответах решения

Comment: А вы сравните регулярку из моего комментария и регулярку из принятого ответа!?

Comment: @Visman только сейчас заметил модификатор u у вас. Может вы отредактировали свои коммент?!

Comment: Это было сделано в первые 15 секунд после отправки комментария.

Comment: @Visman вы добавили модификатор u?

Comment: Я заменил модификатор, так как регулярку брал из вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В регулярных выражениях PCRE в PHP по-умолчанию неактивна поддержка юникода. Обратная совместимость, все дела... Для обработки строк в юникоде обязателен модификатор `u`. (не путать с инверсией жадности `U`).

Ещё странно выглядит отсутствие начального ограничения `^` и избыточный модификатор `i`, когда вы уже и так перечислили регистры.

```
/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁҷҶқҚӯӮҳҲӣӢғҒ]{3,25}$/u
```

По следам комментариев - `^` имеет несколько смыслов. В начале символьной маски - отрицание `[^A]` - всё, кроме символа A. В регулярном выражении - отмечает начало строки, аналогично как `$` отмечает конец строки. `/^[abc]$/` - совпадёт только в том случае, если строка будет состоять из одного символа a, b или c. `/[abc]$/` - если строка любой длины будет заканчиваться символами a, b или c.

Comment: Да я тщательно еще не изучал регулярные выражение. Спасибо за объяснения, ваш пример сработал

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то модификатор `i` (игнорирование регистра) ни кто не отменял для Юникода. Тут даже недавно пост был по этому поводу: [Откуда известно соответствие между заглавными и строчными (uppercase и lowercase) символами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546671/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-uppercase-%D0%B8-lowercase)

А регулярка будет такой:

```
/^[a-zа-яёҷқӯҳӣғ]{3,25}$/iu
```